# Event loop created by asyncio.new_event_loop hangs

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio, event-loop, python-3.5

The following code just hangs without ever printing anything:

```
import asyncio

async def foo(loop):
    print('foo')
    loop.stop()

loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
asyncio.ensure_future(foo(loop))
loop.run_forever()
```

If I use [get_event_loop](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloops.html#asyncio.get_event_loop) everything works fine. Is there something I'm doing wrong or have I stumbled upon a bug?

I'm using Python 3.5.1.

Comment: `ensure_future()` accepts optional `loop` parameter, you should pass it to don't clash with default one.

Actually I highly recommend to use explicit loops only in asyncio applications.

Comment: Oh my... I just started a bounty on the wrong question instead of mine :-/, if you can help me here: stackoverflow.com/questions/35861175/… I will gladly award you the bounty.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

[`asyncio.AbstractEventLoopPolicy.new_event_loop` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloops.html#asyncio.AbstractEventLoopPolicy.new_event_loop) says:

> If there’s need to set this loop as the event loop for the current
>   context, `set_event_loop()` must be called explicitly.

---

```
import asyncio

async def foo(loop):
    print('foo')
    loop.stop()

loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
asyncio.set_event_loop(loop) # <----
asyncio.ensure_future(foo(loop))
loop.run_forever()
```

Comment: Ah, I did see that at some point but I forgot to try it. Probably I thought I don't need it since I wasn't quite sure what it meant! Thanks.

Comment: Oh my... I just started a bounty on the wrong question instead of mine :-/, if you can help me here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35861175/what-can-cause-asyncio-to-hang-upon-simply-creating-a-new-loop I will gladly award you the bounty.